# Flowframe not moving to next page

Tags: flowfram

I tried to extend this flowframe to next page which is not happening. Even tried defining page numbers [1-2], still compiler is not aligning the text.
I need the flow continue over next page.  It is restricting me to single page

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document properties and packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{memoir}

% misc
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{bch}  % font
\pagestyle{empty}                   % no pagenumbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}         % no paragraph indentation


% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage{flowfram}                                       % column layout
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage{graphicx}                                       % figures
\usepackage{url}                                            % URLs
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}                    % color
\usepackage{multicol}                                       % columns env.
    \setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{paralist}                                       % compact lists
\usepackage{tikz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Create column layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define length commands
\setlength{\vcolumnsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\vcolumnsep}

% frame setup (flowfram package)
% left frame
\newflowframe{0.2\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
    \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
    \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.2\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{2\columnsep}
% right frame
\newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]

% horizontal rule between frames (using TikZ)
\renewcommand{\ffvrule}[3]{%
\hfill
\tikz{%
    \draw[loosely dotted,color=RoyalBlue,line width=1.5pt,yshift=-#1] 
    (0,0) -- (0pt,#3);}%
\hfill\mbox{}}
\insertvrule{flow}{1}{flow}{2}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define macros (for convience)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Sep}{\vspace{1.5em}}
\newcommand{\SmallSep}{\vspace{0.5em}}

\newenvironment{AboutMe}
    {\ignorespaces\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} About me}}
    {\Sep\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\CVSection}[1]
    {\Large\textbf{#1}\par
    \SmallSep\normalsize\normalfont}

\newcommand{\CVItem}[1]
    {\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} #1}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% Left frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Upload your own photo using the files menu
\begin{figure}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{cv-photo.png}
    \vspace{-7cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{flushright}\small
    Johnathan S. Doe \\
    \url{jdoe@email.com}  \\
    \url{www.website.com} \\
    (555) 555-3333
\end{flushright}\normalsize
\framebreak


% Right frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\Huge\bfseries {\color{RoyalBlue} John Doe} \\
\Large\bfseries  Graphics designer \\

\normalsize\normalfont

% About me
\begin{AboutMe}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\end{AboutMe}

% Experience
\CVSection{Experience}
\CVItem{May 2010 - present, Lorem ipsum}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla.
\SmallSep

\CVItem{Aug 2007 - Feb 2010, Vivamus vel}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus.
\Sep

% Education
\CVSection{Education}
\CVItem{2010 - present, Lorem ipsum dolor}\\
MSc. Lorem ipsum, Cras sollicitudin
\SmallSep

\CVItem{2007 - 2010, Lorem ipsum dolor}\\
MSc. Lorem ipsum, Cras sollicitudin
\SmallSep

\CVItem{2005 - 2007, Vivamus vel bibendum}\\
Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla.
\Sep

% Skills
\CVSection{Skills}
\CVItem{Platforms}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem 
    \item Ipsum 
\end{compactitem}
\end{multicols}
\SmallSep

\CVItem{Computer software}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem 
    \item Ipsum 
    \item Dolor 
    \item Sit 
    \item Amet
    \item Consectetur 
    \item Adipiscing 
    \item Elit
    \item \ldots
\end{compactitem}
\end{multicols}
\Sep 

% References
\CVSection{References}
References upon request.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% End document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: To downvoter: Please leave a comment, so that the OP has a chance for improvement.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thank you for providing a MWE!

Answer (score 1):

Your MWE doesn't actually have two pages worth of text, so I've added some extra dummy text using the [`lipsum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) package. The problem is that the text in the right frame on page one flows into the much narrower left frame on page two, which causes TeX a problem as it can't adjust the line width mid-paragraph. However, I suspect that you actually want the text in the right frame on page one to flow into the right frame on page two. In which case the left frame is better suited as a dynamic frame and the contents can be set using the `dynamiccontents` (or `dynamiccontents*`) environment or one of the commands such as `\setdynamiccontents`. Here's a modification of your MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final,oneside]{memoir}

% misc
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{bch}  % font
\pagestyle{empty}                   % no pagenumbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}         % no paragraph indentation


% required packages (add your own)
\usepackage{flowfram}                                       % column layout
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}% margins
\usepackage{graphicx}                                       % figures
\usepackage{url}                                            % URLs
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}                    % color
\usepackage{multicol}                                       % columns env.
    \setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{paralist}                                       % compact lists
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Create column layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define length commands
\setlength{\vcolumnsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\vcolumnsep}

% frame setup (flowfram package)
% left frame
\newdynamicframe{0.2\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
    \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
    \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.2\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{2\columnsep}

\setdynamicframe*{left}{clear}

% right frame
\newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]

% horizontal rule between frames (using TikZ)
\renewcommand{\ffvrule}[3]{%
\hfill
\tikz{%
    \draw[loosely dotted,color=RoyalBlue,line width=1.5pt,yshift=-#1] 
    (0,0) -- (0pt,#3);}%
\hfill\mbox{}}
\insertvrule*{dynamic}{left}{flow}{main01}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define macros (for convience)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Sep}{\vspace{1.5em}}
\newcommand{\SmallSep}{\vspace{0.5em}}

\newenvironment{AboutMe}
    {\ignorespaces\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} About me}}
    {\Sep\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\CVSection}[1]
    {\Large\textbf{#1}\par
    \SmallSep\normalsize\normalfont}

\newcommand{\CVItem}[1]
    {\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} #1}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% Left frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Upload your own photo using the files menu
\begin{dynamiccontents*}{left}
{\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image}
\par
}

\begin{flushright}\small
    Johnathan S. Doe \\
    \url{jdoe@email.com}  \\
    \url{www.website.com} \\
    (555) 555-3333
\end{flushright}\normalsize
\end{dynamiccontents*}


% Right frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\Huge\bfseries {\color{RoyalBlue} John Doe} \\
\Large\bfseries  Graphics designer \\

\normalsize\normalfont

% About me
\begin{AboutMe}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla. Pellentesque condimentum justo ut ligula feugiat nec facilisis tellus ultricies. Nullam sit amet dictum ipsum. Sed lacus neque, hendrerit eu rhoncus nec, pellentesque vitae sem.
\end{AboutMe}

% Experience
\CVSection{Experience}
\CVItem{May 2010 - present, Lorem ipsum}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus. Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla.
\SmallSep

\CVItem{Aug 2007 - Feb 2010, Vivamus vel}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel bibendum metus.
\Sep

% Education
\CVSection{Education}
\CVItem{2010 - present, Lorem ipsum dolor}\\
MSc. Lorem ipsum, Cras sollicitudin
\SmallSep

\CVItem{2007 - 2010, Lorem ipsum dolor}\\
MSc. Lorem ipsum, Cras sollicitudin
\SmallSep

\CVItem{2005 - 2007, Vivamus vel bibendum}\\
Proin rutrum pharetra molestie. Cras sollicitudin nulla nec leo lobortis in tristique purus pretium. Ut eu felis nulla.
\Sep

% Skills
\CVSection{Skills}
\CVItem{Platforms}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem 
    \item Ipsum 
\end{compactitem}
\end{multicols}
\SmallSep

\CVItem{Computer software}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{compactitem}[\color{RoyalBlue}$\circ$]
    \item Lorem 
    \item Ipsum 
    \item Dolor 
    \item Sit 
    \item Amet
    \item Consectetur 
    \item Adipiscing 
    \item Elit
    \item \ldots
\end{compactitem}
\end{multicols}
\Sep 

% References
\CVSection{References}
References upon request.

\lipsum

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% End document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

The main differences are: the `oneside` class option, changing the left frame to a dynamic frame, and setting its contents using the `dynamiccontents*` environment. I've also used

```
\setdynamicframe*{left}{clear}
```

To clear the left frame after each page break. Remove this line if you don't want that to happen.